# how to use different faces for regular expressions in the same line in font-lock-defaults

Tags: font-lock, major-mode

I'm trying to create a `major-mode` for HTTP requests in emacs, I'm stuck at the syntax coloring for regexs at the same line.

let this be the HTTP request I'm trying to highlight:

```
    GET /print_hello_world HTTP/2.0
    host: mydomain.com
    accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
    accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.5
    accept: */*
    
    {"message" :"hello world"}
```

now in the first line want to highlight the first line `GET` with a face and the endpoint `/print_hello_world` with another, and for headers I want to use a face for header key and another for header value. I tried using:

```lisp
(define-derived-mode http-request-mode prog-mode 
  (setq-local font-lock-defaults '(http-request-font-lock))
  (setq-local comment-start "# "))
  
;;; 
(defvar http-request-font-lock
    `(
        ;; endpoint
        (,(rx
             line-start
             symbol-start (or "GET" "POST" "PATCH" "PUT" "DELETE" "TRACE" "OPTIONS") symbol-end 
             space
             symbol-start (one-or-more (any alphanumeric punct)) symbol-end
             space) .
             'font-lock-file-face)
         ;; method
        (,(rx line-start
                    symbol-start
                    (or "GET" "POST" "PATCH" "PUT" "DELETE" "TRACE" "OPTIONS")
                    symbol-end )
         . 'font-lock-method-face)
         ;; http header key
        (,(rx line-start symbol-start (one-or-more (any alphanumeric ?- ?_)) symbol-end ":") . 'font-lock-header-key-face )
        ;; http header value 
        (,(rx ": " symbol-start (one-or-more not-newline) symbol-end eol) . 'font-lock-header-value-face )
        ))

;;; faces
(defface font-lock-header-key-face
  '((t :foreground "white" :background "blue"))
  "Font Lock mode face used to highlight variable names."
  )

(defface font-lock-method-face
  '((t :weight bold ))
  "Font Lock mode face used to highlight variable names."
  )

(defface font-lock-path-face
  '((t :slant italic :foreground "red"))
  "Font Lock mode face used to highlight variable names."
  )


(defface font-lock-hversion-face
  '((t :foreground "yellow"))
  "Font Lock mode face used to highlight variable names."
  )

(defface font-lock-header-value-face
  '((t :weight bold :slant italic ))
  "Font Lock mode face used to highlight variable names."
  )
```

this will result in the following:

1. neither the method nor the endpoint got highlighted
2. only the header key is hightlighted properly
3. the header value is only hightlighted when I have a line with only this  `: header-value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was supposed to use regex groups and their index to match faces like this:

```
(defvar http-headers-font-lock
    `((,(rx
             line-start
             (group (or "GET" "POST" "PATCH" "PUT" "DELETE" "TRACE" "OPTIONS") space)
             
             (group (+? not-newline) space)
             (group (+? not-newline) ) "\n"
             )
         (1 'font-lock-http-method-face )
         (2 'font-lock-http-path-face )
         (3 'font-lock-http-hversion-face))
        (,(rx
             (group (+? (any alnum ?- ?_ ))) "=" (group (+? (any alnum punct )) ) (or "; " "&" eol)
             )
         (1 'font-lock-http-lvalue-key-face)
         
         )
        (,(rx
                (group (+? (any alnum ?- ?_ ))) ": " (group (+? (any alnum punct space)) eol))
         (1 'font-lock-http-header-key-face)
         (2 'font-lock-http-header-value-face)
         )
        
        )
    )
```